# different levels (including custom level) on different appenders in log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2

I wanna to log special messages in 2 of my classes into DB and also wanna to write all of my program logs on console.In order to achieve this i defined a custom level(managerLogsLevel) with intLevel=50 for JDBC appender,but i couldn't set the log4j2.xml to do my exact purpose.here is my xml file:

```
<CustomLevels>

    <CustomLevel name="managerLogsLevel" intLevel="50" />

</CustomLevels>

<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss a } %level %c - %m %n" />
    </Console>
    <JDBC name="MySQLDatabase" tableName="phonebook_finalproject.eventlog">
        <ConnectionFactory class="ir.maktabsharif.core.base.ConnectionFactory"
            method="getConnection" />
        <Column name="time" isEventTimestamp="true" />
        <Column name="name" pattern="%logger" />
        <Column name="level" pattern="%level" />
        <Column name="description" pattern="%m" />
    </JDBC>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>

    <Root level="info" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="info" />
    </Root>

    <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="warn" />

    <Logger name="ir.maktabsharif.api" level="managerLogsLevel" >
        <AppenderRef ref="MySQLDatabase" level="managerLogsLevel" />
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="info" />
    </Logger>

</Loggers>
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ - also why would you use a custom log level rather than simply use a special logger for your "special messages"?

Comment: @D.B. what do you mean by special logger? do you mean using common levels?

Comment: I mean something like `<Logger name="SPECIAL_LOGGER"...` because this way you can just give this logger the necessary appender(s) and in your code just do something like `Logger specialLogger = LogManager.getLogger("SPECIAL_LOGGER")` in the 2 classes where you need it rather than adding a new log level which is available everywhere and harder to translate to another logging framework if you ever need to switch.

Comment: The above is one of many possible solutions, another would be to use `MarkerFilter` (see [log4j2 manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#MarkerFilter)) so that your special appender only accepts messages with a special marker (again see [manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/markers.html)).

Comment: @D.B. Thank you for your guide :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments, I don't think a custom log level is the best solution for your use case:

> I wanna to log special messages in 2 of my classes into DB and also wanna to write all of my program logs on console

I suggested two different solutions in my comments but I want to provide a more complete answer along with some examples. Note that these examples do not send messages to a database, but you can modify the appenders as needed. These examples are just meant to provide an illustration of some general techniques you can use.

This first java class below will use the `Marker`/`MarkerFilter` approach:

```
package example;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Marker;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.MarkerManager;

public class SomeClass {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger();
    private static final Marker SPECIAL_MESSAGE = MarkerManager.getMarker("SPECIAL_MESSAGE");   

    public static void main(String[] args){

        if(LOG.isDebugEnabled())
            LOG.debug("This is some debug!");
        LOG.info("Here's some info!");
        //To log a special kind of message use the same logger but include the marker
        LOG.info(SPECIAL_MESSAGE, "Something special goes here");
        LOG.error("Some error happened!");
    }
}
```

This next class (below) will use the "special logger" approach:

```
package example;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class SomeClass2 {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger();
    private static final Logger SPECIAL_LOG = LogManager.getLogger("SPECIAL_LOGGER");   

    public static void main(String[] args){

        if(LOG.isDebugEnabled())
            LOG.debug("This is some debug!");
        LOG.info("Here's some info!");
        //To log a special kind of message use the special logger
        SPECIAL_LOG.info("Something special goes here");
        LOG.error("Some error happened!");
    }
}
```

Here is the log4j2.xml file which contains configuration for both approaches:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>

        <File name="SpecialAppender" fileName="logs/special.log" immediateFlush="false"
            append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
            <MarkerFilter marker="SPECIAL_MESSAGE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </File>

        <File name="SpecialAppenderNoFilter" fileName="logs/specialNoFilter.log" immediateFlush="false"
            append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>

        <!-- This logger uses the MarkerFilter method -->
        <Logger name="example.SomeClass" level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="SpecialAppender" />
        </Logger>

        <!-- The following logger is used for the "special logger" method -->

        <Logger name="SPECIAL_LOGGER" level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="SpecialAppenderNoFilter" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

These two approaches are very similar, but do have their differences:

1. The `Marker` solution requires you to create a `Marker` object whereas the logger solution requires a second `Logger` object.
2. The output of the `Marker` solution still provides you with a meaningful logger name whereas the logger solution requires a general logger name that does not give you any clues about where the messages were generated.
3. The `Marker` solution requires a `MarkerFilter` in the configuration file whereas the logger solution requires a dedicated `Logger` in the configuration.

As I mentioned in the comments another consideration is how easy it would be to migrate your logging strategy to another logging framework if necessary. The `Marker` solution might be more difficult if the framework you're migrating to does not support a marker concept. It appears that [slf4j does support markers](https://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#fatal) so if you move to a framework that has an slf4j binding then there's a good chance the marker would still work.

Comment: I used your "special logger" solution and it works,thanks for it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @D.B.